# No applicable aggregate method “Sum” exists at character 22 in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a form that will be used to collect info on conferences attended (one repeating box), and lectures attended (a repeating box within the first repeating box).

I have calculated the number of hours per conference and would like to take that calculation and add it up to give a final tally of all conferences attended. I am using the following:

```
=ConferenceInformation.Sum(NumberOfHoursForConference)
```

Which is identical to the method used to calculate the individual conference total, but I just can't get it to work for the final total. What am I doing wrong? I get the error about the aggregate method at `character 22 (Sum)`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a really good use of both [Repeating Sections](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/repeating-sections) and [Calculations](https://www.cognitoforms.com/features/calculations) in Cognito Forms, and providing this advanced capability was one of our key goals in building the product.

In this case I suspect the error message is misleading and the problem is actually not this calculation but your other calculation.  Your Calculation field, `NumberOfHoursForConference`, is likely configured to be of type `Text` instead of `Number`.  Because of this, in your secondary calculation, you are seeing an error because there is no way to sum up `Text` values.

[image]

Please change the type of the first Calculation field to `Number` and see if this resolves the issue.  Please comment here either way since this is an educated guess without additional evidence.